# How to get a Header Name from the table at runtime in vb.net

Tags: jquery, html, vb.net, linq

I have a usercontrol with the below code that derives the status,dates from the query at run time on to the page. In the same way i want to get a Header name from the table itself.It should appear below the 'Test Approvals'.I need to get the Caption below the 'Task Approvals' div.

```
    <div>
       <div >Task Approvals</div>
        <div class="tableCaption">  //Need to get caption here 

        </div>
     <div >
       <div class="tableCaption"></div>
       <asp:Panel ID="NoApprvlPnl1" runat="server">
          <div style="padding:5px 0px 5px 0px;"><strong>* None *</strong></div>
       </asp:Panel>
       <asp:Panel ID="ApprvlPnl1" runat="server">
       <asp:Repeater ID="ApprvlRepeater1" runat="server">     

    </asp:Repeater>
    </asp:Panel> 

</div>
<div class="lmbottom"></div>
</div>
```

And the Query i am using to get these fields are :

```
Dim Qry = From x In db.Approvals _
                  Join y In db.Tasks On y.TASK_ID Equals x.TASK_ID
                  Join t In db.Trig On t.TRIGGER_ID Equals x.TRIGGER_ID
                  Where x.TASK_ID = thisTaskId _
                     And x.APPROVAL_RQST_ID = GetRqstID(thisTaskId) _
                    Select ApprvlLbl = GetUserDescr(x.APPROVER_ID), CURRSTATUS = GetActDesc(x.ACTION_STATUS), Appcaption = t.EMAIL_GROUP
```

I want to get the 'Appcaption' as the hearder Text. 
    Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got it by adding the below line

```
   <div class="tableCaption">  //Need to get caption here 
     <span style="padding:5px 0 5px 8px;"><strong><%=Caption%></strong></span>
    </div>
```